# Nummerical truncation on MATLAB - Increase of precision

Tags: integration, truncation-error

It might be not suitable for the current forum, but it is math-related. Than, I wonder if there is a MATLAB user among us. I currently implement multible degrees of Runge-Kutta methods on mentioned software and wonder if there is a way, if any, to improve operations arithmetic precision of operations on the software.

The image below represents the logarithmic error for the Runge Kutta procedure, which exhibits truncation above $10^{-16}$. For some cases (on the beginning of the method) the solution is so precise it does not present error, although it is known there is. Is there some way to improve precision to make a better graphic for such methods?

[image: Runge-Kutta error and truncation]

Comment: MATLAB allows for exact computations with the symbolic toolbox. However, I would guess $10^{-16}$ is more related to storing values as doubles compounded with your system dynamics. Numerically, you'll never reach the true *exact* solution if that's what you're asking

Comment: But I HAVE the exact solution, which, for my case, is the solution of y' = -y. For the case, y(t) = e^{-t} for y_0 = 1.

Comment: Numerically, you cannot *identically* reach the exact solution as the computations for   $e^{-t}$ are inherently different than an iterated solver like RK45. You can play around with the accuracy bounds, but that will only get you so far. See: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/recognize-and-avoid-roundoff-errors.html for a good article on roundoff-error

Comment: Which is the low boundary for accuracy? According to my graph, it is 10^{-17} approximately

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right please see: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html#f2-98739 Also you should note $e^{-t}$ is only the *exact* solution in analytical form. The moment you perform the computation you will run into roundoff-error

Comment: Balls. I will perform my own exp function or increase the precision error for my own delight.